# Why is it needed to set path and CLASSPATH FOR JDK in environment variables only?

Tags: java

I'm not convinced myself why we need to set path for java to run it's applications only in environment variables, why can't in another place? please clarify my doubts.What's meant by environment variables mainly?

Comment: using the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is discouraged. Use the `-cp` option instead for the `java` command.

Comment: "Environment variable" is a standard term in operating system shells and should already be familiar to you. Use your favorite search engine or your library card if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `CLASSPATH` is only a convention. You can load any class only knowing it path. If you do not want to use `CLASSPATH` you can use any other means to obtain a path (Ex: parameters, properties, etc) and load manually your classes.

But, `CLASSPATH` is a way to do things in a decoupled manner.

With the spread use of containers like Docker, we will probable face less problems, like class duplicity, that can occur when we use this `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: It's usually not optimal to set the CLASSPATH environment variable.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you. But, a lot of programs, like IDE, use this resource.

Comment: All Java programs respect the CLASSPATH environment variable unless overridden. Not just a lot, but all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set PATH or CLASSPATH.

Setting the PATH is just to make it easier to run the `java` command. You can always run it using fully qualified name, in which case the PATH is not needed.

Setting the CLASSPATH is never needed, but is sometimes easier than using the `-cp` option. If you run using `-jar`, the CLASSPATH is not used at all, and if you don't use `-jar`, the CLASSPATH is by default the current directory, so if your code is there (i.e. your package hierarchy is rooted there), it's not needed either.

Comment: "so if your code is there" => "so if your package hierarchy is rooted there"